# Drop down list access data from database table stored in App_DA\ata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

this is my model class
public  class Model1
    {
      public string popcorn { get; set; }
        public string pselectedItem { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable items { get; set; }
    }

this is my controller class:-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private rikuEntities rk = new rikuEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Model1
        {
            items = new[]
        {
            new SelectList(rk.emp,"Id","name")

        }
        }; return View(model);
    }


    public ActionResult viewToController(Model1 m)
    {
        string getSelectedName = m.popcorn;
        return Content(getSelectedName);
    }


}
```

this is my view;-

@model chetan.Models.Model1
@using (Html.BeginForm("viewToController", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    
        emp

```
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.popcorn, new SelectList(Model.items))

    </div>
```

```
</fieldset>
```

}

in my example i want to get values in Dropdownlist from database table named "emp" and after select a element of dropdownlist i want to use that element in Index action of Home controller. please check my code carefully and let me know what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your model your model you need `SelectList` and not `IEnumerable<SelectList>`:

```
public class Model1
{
    public string popcorn { get; set; }
    public string pselectedItem { get; set; }
    public SelectList items { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.popcorn, Model.items)
```

The rest of your code seems fine.